# Flash builder vs Flashdevelop full screen size

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flashdevelop

I have created movieclip 480x800 screen size and exsport swc file with flash cs6. Flash builder import swc file and test run my device (Lg l70, 480x800) not full screen, but flashdevelop import and test run it is full screen. How can I full screen for flash builder.

I tried these codes, but could not
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP;

Flash Builder not full screen (gray area)

[image]

Flashdevelop full size

[image: Flashdevelop screen size]

Comment: try tracing [`stage.scaleMode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode)

Comment: I tried these codes, but could not 
      
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL
   stage.align = StageAlign.TOP;